# bootstrap validator : can't get the form to submit (validation ok)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, validation, modal-dialog

I'm writing this question after a long research on the web and in the pugin documentation. I may have missed something here, but I can't find what.

I'm using the bootstrapvalidator (http://bootstrapvalidator.com/) plugin to try to validate form inside a bootstrap modal.

My form code :

```
        <form method="POST" action="/venues/update" accept-charset="UTF-8" id="editForm">
           <input name="id" type="hidden" value="XYZ">
             ... 
             [other form fields...]
             ...
           <button type="submit" class="btn bg-black">Modifier</button>

        </form>
```

my js code for the validation :

```
$('#editForm')
            .bootstrapValidator({
                message: 'Cette valeur ne peut pas être utilisée.',
                feedbackIcons: {
                    valid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok',
                    invalid: 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove',
                    validating: 'glyphicon glyphicon-refresh'
                },
                submitHandler: function(validator, form, submitButton) {
                    alert('submit!!');
                },
                fields: {
                    venue_name: {
                        message: 'Ce nom n\'est pas valide.',
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Le nom du lieu ne peut pas être vide.'
                            },
                            stringLength: {
                                min: 5,
                                max: 30,
                                message: 'Le nom doit être d\'au moins 5 caractères'
                            },
                            regexp: {
                                regexp: /^[a-zA-Z0-9_ ]+$/,
                                message: 'Le nom ne peut pas contenir de caractères spéciaux.'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    max_capacity: {
                        message: 'Cette valeur n\'est pas valide.',
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Ce champs ne peut pas être vide.'
                            },
                            regexp: {
                                regexp: /^[0-9]+$/,
                                message: 'Ce champs nécessite une valeur numérique entière.'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    venue_status: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'Le status doit être défini.'
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    venue_location: {
                        validators: {
                            notEmpty: {
                                message: 'La localisation doit être définie.'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            });
```

My problem is that my validation step works well. The submission of the form does not happen though, so I tried to add this alert test to debug. The alert does not come up either, which seems to indicate that the submitHelper is not triggered. I'm very lost with that now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that you're using the old version of the plugin.
From v0.5.0, the plugin removes `submitHandler` option, according to the [Upgrading to v0.5.0](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/news/upgrading-to-v0.5.0/) guide.
Use the `success.form.bv` event handler instead.

You might try the following code:

```
$('#editForm')
    .bootstrapValidator(options)
    .on('success.form.bv', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault(); // Prevent the form from submitting 
        alert('I am going to do other things');

        // ... Do whatever you want

        // If you want to submit the form, use the defaultSubmit() method
        // http://bootstrapvalidator.com/api/#default-submit
        $('#editForm').bootstrapValidator('defaultSubmit');
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is clear now. All working as expected.

Comment: Thank You for this solution